# Any create custom camera with video compression in android

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, video-processing

I want to create custom camera for my app in which the video is recorded up to custom limit and video is compressed to very low memory size(don't decrease the quality of video).

Comment: Please post your tried code. You couldn't get a ready made solution from SO

Comment: Ok .Have a look at this ...     https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/193853/2415365/oR3BsdO9971a0mi/VideoCameraActivity.java

Comment: Still, your question is too broad bro. Try specifying the issue you are facing. Don't expect some one in SO will give you a clear cut well-built util, because, that rarely happens :-)

Comment: @AbhinandanChada Is that your code? If not, why don't you look at it?

Comment: @cricket_007 it is my code...only problem with this code is video size is too large..

Comment: @DevTest The problem is only that video size is too large...I need to send the video of very small size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing bitrate .... it will have a minimal impact on the quality but will reduce the size